# How to calculate the absolute difference of two unsigned integers?

Tags: c++, overflow, unsigned, unsigned-integer, absolute-value

How can one prevent overflow when calculating the absolute of the difference of two unsigned integers?

The result must be an unsigned integer as well (actually independent of the processer, as it will mathematically be just a number between 0 and MAXINT).

```
unsigned int a;
unsigned int b;

abs(a-b);
```

But this only works if b<=a, otherwise a-b<0 and will then overflow, and taking `abs` later will not help.

What is the easiest, overflow-safe way of doing that calculation?

(Actually I want to test if |a-b|<c where c is some constant.
So, one could check a-bb and b-aa.)

Comment: Can you subtract the smaller value from the larger value?

Comment: You've more or less answered your own question: `if (a > b) return a - b; else return b - a;` (but not on one line)?

Comment: Could you please be more specific in "the easiest" requirement? I.e. why basic `if` or `? ... : ...` does not work?

Comment: @Eljay A priori I don't know which is the smaller number.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes even with ternary operator would be one line.

Comment: @pas-calc I'm totally not understanding what your requirement is than... If "one line" is not suitable for your needs... Please [edit] the post to show what type of code you would like to see as an answer.

Comment: I would have expected something without if/else but pure type casting

Comment: What is wrong with `(a > b) ? (a - b) : (b - a)`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the answers in the comments, one sees a simple solution can be accomplished like that using case differentiation.

```
unsigned int uint_diff(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
  if (a > b){
    return (a - b);
  }
  else {
    return (b - a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Clearly against OP's requirement - "I would have expected something without if/else but pure type casting".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov But this answerer ***is*** the OP. ;)

Comment: @AdrianMole I know :)... sometimes OP needs a reminder that answer should actually answer the question *as asked* instead of writing an answer for whatever they actually *needed* to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple cast ***if*** a `long long signed int` is larger than an `unsigned int` on your platform. It *probably* will be but the Standard does allow `int`, `long` and `long long` to be the same size. *(Note: I specifically used `long long` because on some common platforms – like MSVC/Windows – `long int` is the same size as `int`, as also for the `unsigned` versions.)*

Here's a version that uses `constexpr if` (compile-time) checks and, if neither of the casts will work, falls back on the simpler, test-first solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

unsigned int unsint_diff(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    if constexpr (sizeof(long int) > sizeof(unsigned int)) {
        return static_cast<unsigned int>
            (std::abs(static_cast<long signed int>(a) - static_cast<long signed int>(b)));
    }
    else if constexpr (sizeof(long long int) > sizeof(unsigned int)) {
        return static_cast<unsigned int>
            (std::abs(static_cast<long long signed int>(a) - static_cast<long long signed int>(b)));
    }
    else {
        return (a > b) ? a - b : b - a;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 123456789u;
    unsigned int j = 987654321u;
    std::cout << unsint_diff(i, j) << "\n";
    std::cout << unsint_diff(j, i) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you need the casts on *both* operands of the subtraction because, if the size comparisons are *not* 'successful', then the call to `std::abs` will be using an `unsigned int` argument – which is ambiguous and, thus, the code is ill-formed (and that isn't allowed, even in the body of an `if constexpr` statement that won't actually be used).